# Fail Jenkins job only if there is an error/issue with the job

Tags: maven, jenkins, build, jobs

I have a Jenkins job which runs certain SoapUI test cases using the maven plugin.The Jenkins build fails even if one of the test cases fail.I do not want this to be the case and want the job to fail only when there is an issue with the job(like it terminates in between due to some exception) or if the server is down.How can I do that?

Comment: Jenkins usually will change the build status as unstable  in case of test failures and the status will be failed only if commands cannot be invoked / node is not up etc.

Comment: No, in my case even if the test cases fail the build is marked as failed.

Comment: Can you share additional information on how are you triggering the test - what is the actual job configuration and how is the console output when job fails due to a test failure

Comment: The console output says build failure and throws an exception due to an erroneous HTTP status code.The tests are triggered via a maven build.

Comment: If you can post a screenshot / paste the console out put i can get some insight,bcz if you are triggering test from a maven goal and you get an HTTP exception, not sure if its your test execution is completed and result is failure / there are issues with invoking(or executing) your test

Comment: What happens if the soapui project is run using maven command line? Does it proceeds if one of the test fails? Also try open the soapui project in a text edit and see `abortOnError="false"` set at project level.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to skip test cases in your Maven run? Use the code below in maven properties section of maven plugin:

```
maven.test.failure.ignore=true
```